# Final check progress-indicator lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm trying use the lightning-progress-indicator of lwc.
I want show the final check if step is finished

```
                <lightning-progress-indicator class="path-checks" current-step={showCurrentStep} type="base" has-error={error}>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="Step 1" value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="Step 2" value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
                </lightning-progress-indicator>
```

If showCurrentStep == '2' the bar show this picture
[image]

I want to show a circle if step 2 didn't finish and a green tick if step 2 finished; I can't get the latter

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will work

FR : [DEMO](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/CxZq4ymd8qaDrY09VycJ)

Comment: You can find code in html and js file in DEMO